# Use of data available in async function on node request to update data of the application

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

This is a simplification of a module in nodejs I'm working. 
I know that the function sent as second parameter of request is async. But I cannot understand how I can access that data.
Basically, I need to fetch some external json file, hopefully only once, when the server start (and I call the function requestJson), and use this data to update the global for the module json_data. This json_data will be the data consulted by the api exposed (apicall1 and apicall2, corresponding to getSomeJSONData1 and getSomeJSONData2)

```
var json_data = []; // <-- here I want to put the json data  

var requestJson = function() {
  request({
    url: "example.com/somejson.json",
    json: true
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      //here I have access to the json content
      // how I can do to use the body content 
      // and put it on json_data
    }
  });
}

var getSomeJSONData1 = function() {
  return json_data[0];
};

var getSomeJSONData2 = function() {
  return json_data[1];
};

exports.apicall1 = getSomeJSONData1;
exports.apicall2 = getSomeJSONData2;
```

how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Install `q` module.

```
var json_data = []; // <-- here I want to put the json data  

var requestJson = function() {
  var dfd = q.defer();
  request({
    url: "example.com/somejson.json",
    json: true
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      //assign json_data
      dfd.resolve({});
    } else {
      dfd.reject({});
    }
  });
  return dfd.promise;
}

var getSomeJSONData1 = function() {
  var dfd = q.defer();
  if(json_data.length){
    dfd.resolve(json_data[0]);
  } else {
    requestJson()
      .then(function(res) {
        dfd.resolve(json_data[0]);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        dfd.reject('error');
      });
  }
  return dfd.promise;
};

var getSomeJSONData2 = function() {
  var dfd = q.defer();
  if(json_data.length){
    dfd.resolve(json_data[1]);
  } else {
    requestJson()
      .then(function(res) {
        dfd.resolve(json_data[1]);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        dfd.reject('error');
      });
  }
  return dfd.promise;
};

exports.apicall1 = getSomeJSONData1;
exports.apicall2 = getSomeJSONData2;
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the `request-promise` module, which uses node's native `Promise` implementation (instead of `q`). This overall pattern is good, but that will simplify the code.

Comment: That's true. But I prefer using `q`. Think using of `q` make code more readable. But thanks for recommend. @murrayju

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee thanks for your answer, but there is still something I cannot understand. When I could query the apicall1 and apicall2? Because I tried from an ajax call from my client page, but it still receive an empty json

Comment: Can you insert your ajax usage in client side??

Comment: Did you modify this part of code?? `dfd.resolve({});` in `requestJson` function?@Nisanio